# PIC18 preserving EEPROM data during reprogramming

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, eeprom, pickit

I am using PIC18f4550 microcontroller to store some data in EEPROM so that the data can be accessible after the power reset.

When I reprogram the PIC with PICkit3, it seems to wipe out the EEPROM data I have stored.

After searching for a while, I found out that there is "Preserve EEPROM Memory" option on Pickit3 properties.  I have trouble selecting the "Preserve EEPROM Range" as no matter what I key in, it still shows red.

[image]

What is the correct value to put in so that I can preserve my EEPROM data?

Comment: maybe the program memory has to start at 100

Comment: With a PIC18F25k22 it works fine foe me. (MPLABX5.45)

Answer (score 1):

For "Memories to Program", uncheck "EEPROM" (the third row)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the range 0xF00000 - 0xF000FF

Comment: it doesn't work for me. MPLabx still indicating it is outside the area